# ¿Cómo mostrar el detalle de una noticia de diferentes tablas?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo 6 tablas, debido al portal de noticias diferente, en el que el diseño de la página principal se clasifica de la siguiente manera.

- Donde se muestran diferentes portadas, con diferentes categorías, las noticias más vistas, las noticias más populares, las nuevas noticias, más noticias, próximos partidos, hoy partidos en vivo, entre otros.
- El diseño de la portal se puede observar en la siguiente [plantilla de demostración](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/may-2016/01-05-2016/live_info/web/) es por ello que las noticias se dividen en 6 tablas diferentes.

De la siguiente manera, el detalle de las noticias se muestra sin problema.

```
<?php
  require "app/php/require.ini.php";
  include "app/php/date_es.php";
  include 'themes/template/header.php';

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id'];
  }

    $stmtID = $con->prepare("SELECT id_mini_cover,cover_page,title,description,url,date_post,detail FROM mini_cover WHERE url=? limit 1");
    $stmtID->bind_param("s",$url);
    $stmtID->execute();
    $stmtID->store_result();

  $stmtID->bind_result($id_mini_cover, $cover_page, $title, $description, $url, $date_post, $detail);

  if ($stmtID->fetch()) {
    include 'app/themes/detail_mini_cover.ini.php';
    } else {
    echo "No existe noticia";
    }
  include 'themes/template/footer.php';
?>
```

Todo se ve tan bien, incluso las elegantes URLs amigables.

```
ejemplo.com/world-russia-2018/
```

Por medio del archivo .htaccess `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport.php?id=$1`

Ahora el problema es que no sé cómo mostrar el detalle de las otras noticias de las otras tablas.

Intente crear un archivo similar a `all_sport.php` con otro nombre `all_sport_one.php` y con otros datos de consulta, para las otras tablas, pero me muestra el mensaje que no hay noticias, cuando accedo a una URLs de una noticia de aquella consulta, que si existe.

A pesar de haber puesto otra línea al .htaccess no funcionó.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport_one.php?id=$1
```

¿Me pueden explicar cómo puedo mostrar el detalle de una noticia tomando en cuenta las 6 tablas diferentes?

*Por decir en estos momentos como para tener un ejemplo para yo guiarme,*
Como muestro los detalles de la primera consulta al igual que esta segunda consulta.

> Y así sucesivamente con las otras 4 consultas faltantes de las 6 tablas.

```
<?php
  require "app/php/require.ini.php";
  include "app/php/date_es.php";
  include 'themes/template/header.php';

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id'];
  }

    $stmtID = $con->prepare("SELECT id_mini_cover,cover_page,title,description,url,date_post,detail FROM mini_cover WHERE url=? limit 1");
    $stmtID->bind_param("s",$url);
    $stmtID->execute();
    $stmtID->store_result();

  $stmtID->bind_result($id_mini_cover, $cover_page, $title, $description, $url, $date_post, $detail);

  if ($stmtID->fetch()) {
    include 'app/themes/detail_mini_cover.ini.php';
    } else {
    echo "No existe noticia";
    }
  include 'themes/template/footer.php';
?>
```

---

## Información Adicional

El siguiente código:

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id'];
  }
```

Obtiene los datos de la URL, por ejemplo: world-russia-2018/

Los datos obtenidos de la URL, pasan ser una condición para la consulta en `WHERE url=?`, para así reflejar el detalle de esa noticia, que conicida con aquella URL en los registros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que puedas tener dos reglas iguales en el mismo .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport_one.php?id=$1
```

como ambas buscan lo mismo, ¿como podría saber a qué php redirigir?

Probablemente siempre se vaya por la primera (all_sport.php)

Quizás una solución es agregar algo adicional que te permita distinguir una url de otra.

Por ejemplo

`ejemplo.com/world-russia-2018/` te llevaría a `all_sport.php?id=world-russia-2018`

Mientras que

`ejemplo.com/lo-que-sea/one` te llevaría a `all_sport_one.php?id=lo-que-sea`

Es sólo una posibilidad. Otra opción sería crear una distinción en la url antes del id:

```
ejemplo.com/mundial/world-russia-2018/ => all_sport.php?id=world-russia-2018
ejemplo.com/futbol/realcd-mallorca/  => all_sport_one.php?id=realcd-mallorca
```

Para este último caso, serían algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^mundial/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^futbol/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport_one.php?id=$1
```

También puede resultarte interesante agregar una regla adicional 'genérica' como la que utilizabas. Y que se utilizaría en caso de no entrar por las de 'categoría'. Lo que deberías verificar que es la última regla porque 'encuentra cualquier cosa' y si es la primera no da opción a las demás.

Así pues la última regla podría ser algo como:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ otro_php_que_hace_otra_cosa.php?id=$1
```

Comment: es exactamente lo que sucede amigo con las reglas .htacces porque no diferencia a cuál es, por lo tanto que regla debo emplear para que funcione crear un archivo diferente por mostrar los detalles de cada producto por cada tabla que tengo.

Comment: si amigo siempre va `all_sport.php` mientras que al otro no lo toma en cuenta :(

Comment: has dado buenas ideas, pero como debo emplear las reglas amigo :)

Comment: Deberías tener "2 formatos" de url, uno para cada php, de manera que puedas distinguirlas de alguna manera. Arriba en el comentario puse dos ejemplos (uno que termina en /one y otro que tiene una especie de categoría al inicio) De nuevo, son ejemplos, el tema es que deberías poder distinguir las urls de alguna manera. Una vez que hayas pensado como distinguirlas te puedo ayudar con las expresiones regular a utilizar para cada una.

Comment: He pensado en la expresión de agregarle una categoría, las expresiones que deseo es mostrarlas así entonces: `ejemplo.com/mundial/world-russia-2018/`

Comment: Y así para diferenciar el otro archivo `ejemplo.com/futbol/realcd-mallorca/`

Comment: las categorías quedan mucho mejor, ayúdame como emplear la reglas htacces para que mis archivos las puedan indentificar gracias :)

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta agregando las reglas para el segundo ejemplo

Comment: También te puede resultar interesante tener una url 'genérica' (sin categorías) con la regla original que tenías. Lo que deberías asegurarte de que esta regla siempre fuera la última, para de esta manerla darle opción a las demás reglas. La regla original que tenías 'encuentra cualquier cosa' y si es la primera no da opción a las demás

Comment: suena interesante lo que me comentas amigo, puedes darme un ejemplo agregado más detalle a su respuesta amigo :)

Comment: @Luis gracias amigo :) más tarde pruebo la solución que me has dado, ahora estoy en el trabajo gracias nuevamente :)